# SpringFox Boot starter: How to disable swagger-ui for production profile?

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox-boot-starter

I am using the io.springfox `springfox-boot-starter` v 3.0.0,

According to the documentation, this Spring Boot setup would disable the swagger endpoint for prod:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

...
```

When on prod, the *customisations* of swagger defined here are indeed missing, but the Swagger UI *endpoint* is still there. How can I suppress the `/swagger-ui/` endpoint altogether? Is there nothing like a `springfox.swagger-ui.enabled=false` property I can set somewhere in the spring boot application configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable using below property

```
springfox.documentation.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Springfox Boot Starter API enable by default the 'auto-startup' configuration, means Swagger UI html page (ex. /swagger-ui/index.html) and Api-Docs (/v2/api-docs) JSON page containing a swagger with All API definitions.

For production environment is a good choise disable all the API documentation.

To disable all the swagger auto-configurations you can add on your application-prod.properties file the property below:

`springfox.documentation.auto-startup=false`

In this case with Your config on prod you have nothing about swagger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the swagger-related resources completely, consider do it in the compile-time.

If you are using Apache Maven, it is easy to control dependencies and runtime configuration in a Maven profile, eg `swagger`.

When building for production, run the following command.

```sh
mvn package -Pprod

// for dev stage.
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Pdev,swagger
```

[My example](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-springmvc-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hantsylabs/restexample/springmvc/config/SwaggerConfig.java) is a little old which used Maven to control different configuration  in different stage.

Comment: Thank you, we build one package for tst/acc/prd, and on tst and acc we do want the swagger ui. Otherwise this would have worked for us.